# Different results with LocalDateTime by different calls with same parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot

The problem is, that I have to change my code from Calendar object to LocalDateTime object. But I don't get the same timestamp at the end. In the first call I got the same with localDateTime, on the next calls I get other timestamps and I use the same parameter to calculate the timestamps. I don't know why I get different results. It isn't logic for me. What I want to do is: I get a UTC Timestamp. I want to set it on german(Europe/Berlin) time(important about summer and winter season). Then I want to calculate the start of the day(00:00) and the end of the day(23:59). Then I want to get the timestamp for this times.

I build an API with spring-boot. The above described function is invoked by a controller class from spring-boot. The first call after the start of the API calculates the expected results. But all next calls give other results. Always with 7200 difference. I tried other ways with localDateTime, but it never gaves the same timestamp as with calendar.

LocalDateTimeWay:

```
LocalDateTime localDateTime = 
LocalDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochSecond(timestamp), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime dayStartLocal = localDateTime.withHour(0)
    .withMinute(0)
    .withSecond(0)
    .withNano(0);

ZonedDateTime startZonedDateTime = dayStartLocal.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long dayStartTimeStamp = startZonedDateTime.toInstant().getEpochSecond();

LocalDateTime dayEndLocal = localDateTime.withHour(23)
    .withMinute(59)
    .withSecond(59)
    .withNano(999);

ZonedDateTime endZonedDateTime = dayEndLocal.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
long dayEndTimeStamp = endZonedDateTime.toInstant().getEpochSecond();
```

CalendarWay:

```
Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTimeInMillis(timestamp*1000);
cal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Berlin"));

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);
long dayStartTimeStamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;

cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,23);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,59);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,59);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,999);

long dayEndTimeStamp = calendar.getTimeInMillis()/1000L;
```

I want by the param timestamp 1536933600. The result 1536876000 and 1536962399. But I get after the first request by localDateTime method 1536883200 and 1536969599.

Comment: Some nitpicking: 1. setting each field manually as you do for calendars is a bad style for new API, since each call of a `with` method creates a new date-time object. This is just wasteful. Use `localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)`, and `localDateTime.with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT.minusNanos(1))`. 2. If you want millisecond-based timestamps, you should work with `ZonedDateTime` objects from the very start instead of converting them separately.

Comment: Another thing: `localDateTime.withNano(999)` is absolutely **not** the same as `calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999)`, by several orders of magnitude not the same, in fact.

Comment: And 4th nitpick: you don't need to convert a `ZonedDateTime` to `Instant` to get to epoch seconds value. A method `toEpochSecond()` is right on the `ZonedDateTime` type for you to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using system default zone for your `java.time` code and Europe/Berlin zone for `Calendar` code. The `7200` is most likely the difference between your system time zone and Europe/Berlin (2 hours).

Replace all `ZoneId.systemDefault()` with `ZoneId.of("Europe/Berlin")` and you will get the same values in both versions:

```
timestamp = 1536933600
dayStartTimeStamp = 1536876000
dayEndTimeStamp = 1536962399
```